# Multiple TCP Connections to download simple webpage and images?

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark

I created a very simple webpage:

```
<html>
<body>
foo bar
<img src="img1.png"/>
<img src="img2.png"/>
<img src="img3.png"/>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

And each image is a simple color square 900 bytes in size (fits in one TCP packet each).

I then used wireshark to record the TCP packets, I expected there to be only one connection/stream, however there were 3. The first one requested the HTML file, got the response, then requested img1.png, and got it's response. The other 2 connections got img2 and img3 each. The other 2 connections were made before the first had finished.

I thought it was not necessary with HTTP 1.1 to have multiple TCP connections? Why doesn't the browser just keep using the first connection, surely it's less expensive?

I tried this on Safari, Chrome and Firefox all with identical results.

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/631345/blogs/Maximum-concurrent-connection-domain-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers use multi-threading, and as such use multiple threads to get and process various elements/resources from the page.

This is done so that resources can be downloaded and processed in parallel, making it (possibly/probably) faster overall.

So instead of:

`Download -> Process -> Display -> Download -> Process -> Display -> Download -> Process -> Display`

to get and display the three images, it's three `Download -> Process -> Display`'s happening at once.

That way one resource can be processed and displayed without waiting for others to finish first.

Imagine 2 tiny images and one large one. The two tiny ones will be displayed without waiting for the large one to finish, therefor delivering content quicker.